# Refresh MediaStore for Images & Videos

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gallery, mediastore, android-mediascanner

I moving and deleting lots of images and videos as per my requirement and now i am scan media by using

```
Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
```

all working fine but sometime freeze the screen, i think some issue in MediaScanner.

And my second quetion is how to scan all media Store rether than scan perticuler File.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this solution for amove and delete the image.

**Pass file directory path inside deleteRecursive(fileOrDirectory) and you can delete multiple and the single image from file or directory.**

```
public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (!fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) return;
    File[] childFiles = fileOrDirectory.listFiles();
    if (childFiles == null) return;
    if (childFiles.length == 0) {
        fileOrDirectory.delete();
    } else {
        for (File childFile : childFiles) {
            deleteRecursive(childFile);
            DeleteAndScanFile(MainActivity.this, childFile.getPath(), childFile);
        }
    }


}

private void DeleteAndScanFile(final Context context, String path,
                               final File fi) {
    String fpath = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    try {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/abc/"
                        + fpath.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        if (uri != null) {
                            context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null,
                                    null);
                        }
                        fi.delete();
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It's Good work for me, Hope this help you...if you need any help you can ask

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am deleting multiple images in loop so Should i scan media every time in loop?, can't we scan after loop?

Answer (score 4):

Use `MediaScannerConnection` instead.

```
public void callScanItent(Context context,String path) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[] { path }, null,null);
}
```

**OR**

```
 public void callScanItent(Context context,String path) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[]{path}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.d("Scan complete for: ",path);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am deleting multiple images in loop so Should i scan media every time in loop?, can't we scan after loop?

Comment: As you see the second parameter  Array of paths to be scanned. So yeah you can pass the complete array at the end of loop to scan .

Comment: Yeah i'll try this THANKS, Give my quetion up vote so i can Up vote you , i need 15 rep to upvote you.

Comment: Well it should work as documentation says . and also i have tested it its working at my end too. Check the path array you are passing should contain valid path.